# Authenticate B2C User using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I have a **Blazor Server Application** with **AD B2C** authentication. I'm currently using `GraphServiceClient` to retrieve the users, groups etc... I have a **User Flow** created for **Sign In and Sign Out**. I can login to the **AD B2C** and retrieve claims.

I want to have a custom UI and its color and images matches with the application and login to the **AD B2C** using this custom UI. Can I achieve that with `GraphServiceClient`? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

If you have user flows defined in AAD B2C tenant and want them properly branded to match application then you need to prepare your own UI templates (HTML + CSS) for those flows and setup flows to use them.

Here's how you do that:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html

Comment: My question is on achieving it with ```GraphServiceClient```. I don't want to use any UI template.